# create a private class in a test method

Tags: python

I am trying to do this in a test method:

```
def test_init(self):
    class args:
        def __init__(self):
            self.server = "myserver"
            self.project = "myproject"

    print(args.server)
    print(args.project)
    CommandFile(args)
```

on first appearance, it looks like it should work just fine, passing an args object to my class constructor.  but for some reason its not.  Pretty sure its a syntax issue, but I never tried this with python before so im not sure.  any ideas?

Comment: You're referencing `args.server` and `args.project` before you've assigned values to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused between class and instance variables. `args` is a class, and doesn't have `server` or `project` attributes. An instance of `args` *would* have those attributes, because they're assigned in `__init__`, but you never instantiate an object so that method is never called.

If you stuck to standard PEP8 naming syntax the confusion would be less likely to arise, since you would call the class `Args` and an instance `args`.

Comment: ugh, im a retard.  goes with a 36 hour deployment stretch.   Thanks